# How to change outline color with eyedropper in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, shapes, eyedropper

I am trying to work on a big project and i need to change lines color just with **one click**, the is so much shapes, every time i pick i dropper it changes the shapes color not only the outline
Any solution???

Comment: Have you tried selecting all objects with the same stroke color? You can do this by going to "Select -> Same -> Stroke Color". Make sure you're choosing to change the stroke and not the fill color.

Comment: Do what Andrew posts.. it can save hours. Or... to continue with the Eyedropper, double click the Eyedropper Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select one of those shapes.
- Go to Main menu » Select » Same » Stroke Color,
  which will select every unlocked object using that particular stroke
  color. Note that any locked objects, or objects on locked layers WILL NOT be selected, so make sure everything is unlocked, first.
- Then use the Color panel to edit this color for the
  entire selection, or apply a swatch from the Swatches panel. Make sure you apply to the stroke, not the fill.
- You can also use the eyedropper as per the question, but for that, you need to know how the eyedropper works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was thinking if there was a method like in Corel ( Left mouse click change all selected shapes inside colour and Right mouse click change outline colors ), but this method @Lucian give me helps a lot